# Is there any way to use same payment method for multiple user subscription in laravel cashier?

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

In my laravel project I have one super admin and many users. Super admin need to pay the subscription amount of each user using cashier.

- I tried to subscribe for each users using the payment method of super
  admin it doesn't support.
- I tried to add  payment method of super    admin to all the users it
  doesn't support.
- I am trying to buy  multiple quantities product in super admin  account using `$user->subscription('default')->incrementQuantity(5);` but I don't know how to allocate this purchased quantity to another user according to cashier concept.

Or is there any other method to use same payment method for multiple user subscription(except simple charge)

Comment: Are the users going to pay for the quantity? or just the super user pays and give to users without the users paying

Comment: super user pays and give to users without the users paying

Comment: Last Question... are users subscribed to a plan on your app? if yes, then to add the quantities to users will be easy

Comment: Thanks for your comments.But user can buy monthly or yearly plan. I tried to assign  quantities but I got error  while assigning multiple plans with different time interval to same subscriptions.I am planning to create two subscription with different plans then add quantities.Still stuck on how to overwrite webhook controller and assign this subscription to particular users.

Comment: From what i understand, The Super user can purchase more quantities which is to be allocated to a user. In your app, why not create a button on your user's table(not db table).. where you can click and update a user's quantity and create a function/Controller method that does the incrementQuantity() for the user and decrementQuantity() for the admin. or is it that you want all the process done automatically? when super admin purchase it should just auto allocate to a user ( as that will be a bit difficult to achieve )

Comment: For instance, this ( https://ibb.co/bH9cNpv ) is something i worked on, similar to what you want to do, just that in my case the user is being charged for increasing their quantity (which is called contacts) .. So you could create a modal where you as the super admin can click based on the user and increase their quantity and again, your stripe account/product has to be setup in a way that increase or decrease in quantities doesn't adjust user's subscription price. In my case change in quantity affects the subscription price

Comment: thanks for helping:)